# Specs2/Neo4j - Using ImpermanentGraphDatabase with Specs2

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, specs2

I'm writing an acceptance test using Specs2.

I want to use `ImpermanentGraphDatabase` in order to have an in-memory Neo4j graph; ideal for integration testing.

I set up Spring-Data for Neo4j and my Spring file configuration contains:

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.test.ImpermanentGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown"/>
```

I wonder whether the option `destroy-method="shutdown"`is taking in account with Specs2 instead of usual `JUnit`, in order to isolate each Spec's `example`.

To sum up: **Would each `example` have its own in-memory graph instance or it would be shared to all of them?**

I guess that it's not applicable since specs2 use the same `Specification` instance for all these Spec's examples execution. Indeed, with the Specs2's functional style, only `is()` method is called englobing all examples in one instance.

I tried also to implement the `BeforeExample` trait in order to clean database at each `example` but... with a Given/Then/When style, it seems that the whole is considered as a unique `example`. Indeed, the separator is `^` instead of traditional `!`, the latter representing one `example`.

I would like to clean in-memory database (`ImpermanentGraphDatabse`) before each step (`Given` or `When` or `Then` step)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of your problem is that you want a "fresh" database before each group of Given/When/Then steps.

In order to do this you can either:

- specify the action explicitly before each group of Given/When/Then steps

  ```
  Step(cleanupDatabase) ^
  "A given-when-then example for the addition" ^
    "Given the following number: ${1}"         ^ number1 ^
    "And a second number: ${2}"                ^ number2 ^
    "And a third number: ${3}"                 ^ number3 ^
                                               end^
  Step(cleanupDatabase) ^
  "A given-when-then example for the addition" ^
   "Given the following number: ${1}"         ^ number1 ^
   "And a second number: ${2}"                ^ number2 ^
   "And a third number: ${3}"                 ^ number3 ^
                                           end
  ```
- use functions to declare each group and map a cleanup step before each

  ```
  def `first example` =     
    "A given-when-then example for the addition" ^
      "Given the following number: ${1}"         ^ number1 ^
      "And a second number: ${2}"                ^ number2 ^
      "And a third number: ${3}"                 ^ number3 ^
                                                 end
  def `second example` =     
    "A given-when-then example for the addition" ^
      "Given the following number: ${1}"         ^ number1 ^
      "And a second number: ${2}"                ^ number2 ^
      "And a third number: ${3}"                 ^ number3 ^
                                                 end

  def is = Seq(`first example`, `second example`).foldLeft(Step():Fragments) { (res, cur) =>
    res ^ Step(cleanupDatabase) ^ cur 
  }
  ```
- use the [`map` function of the Specification](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#Template) to do it generically

  ```
  override def map(fs: =>Fragments) = fs.flatMap {
    // clean the database at the end of a G/W/T block
    case f if f == end => Seq(Step(cleanDatabase), end)
    case other         => Seq(other)    
  }
  ```

Comment: I like the last suggestion but `End()` is an inaccessible `case class` (because its englobing object is annotated with `private[specs2]`).

Comment: Right, I removed this restriction but also checked my previous answer which did not compile! I'm going to edit that answer and make it a bit nicer with the latest 1.12.4-SNAPSHOT.